# Calculate the integral or prove that it diverges

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, logarithms, improper-integrals

Given integral

$$\int_{1}^{+ \infty} \frac{\ln(x^2 + x)}{x}\, dx,$$

calculate it or prove that it diverges.

I've tried to use integration by parts, but after second application I got the initial integral.

I also thought about the following: since

$$\frac{\ln(x^2 + x)}{x} \geqslant 0 \ \forall x \in [1, +\infty),$$

I may want to get an lower bound (some $g(x)$) such that

$$\frac{\ln(x^2 + x)}{x} \geqslant g(x)  \forall x \in [1, +\infty)$$

and then prove that $g$ diverges. Unfortunately I have no idea, which function to take as $g$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $\ln(x^2+x)$ is increasing on $[1,\infty)$, hence
$$ \frac{\ln(x^2+x)}{x}\geq \frac{\ln(2)}{x} $$
for all $x\geq 1$. And since
$$ \int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x}=\infty $$
this implies that
$$ \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x^2+x)}{x}=\infty$$
as well.

Comment: I wonder how I haven't thought of a constant. Your answer is better than mine.

Comment: Yours is quite nice as well...

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(x^2 + x)}{x}\ \mathrm dx
&>&\displaystyle \int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(x^2)}{x}\ \mathrm dx \\
&=&\displaystyle 2\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x}\ \mathrm dx \\
&=&\displaystyle 2\int_1^\infty \ln x \ \mathrm d(\ln x) \\
&=&\displaystyle 2\left(\dfrac12 (\ln x)^2\right)_1^\infty \\
&=&\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} (\ln n)^2 \\
&=&\infty
\end{array}$$